# Powershell compare if statement not working

Tags: powershell

I am writing PowerShell script that will look at txt file `$file_list` and then compare filename within that file to files within a `/bin` directory.

If they match it will then move that file to a specified folder `$destination_folder`.

The issue is that the `if` statement is not executing - it will attempt to move **all** the files from the `/bin` to `$destination_folder`.

```
$file_list = Get-Content "C:\files\Patching\Worker\list.txt"
$search_folder = “C:\Program Files\NetBrain\Worker Server\bin”
$destination_folder = “C:\files\Patching\Backups”


foreach ($item in $file_list) {
  $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Filter $file -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % { $_.FullName}
  $destination_folder = “C:\files\Patching\Backups”

  if ($file_to_move.name -like $item) {
    Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
  }
}
```

Comment: Point 1) Fix the quotes in the code. The curly quotes cannot work. Point 2) Show the content of `list.txt`. It's impossible to tell why you filtering does not work when you don't show your filter strings.

Comment: Agreed please show a example of whats in list.txt

Comment: @Tomalak *The curly quotes cannot work.* Can you explain this? This four `"“”„` are valid double quote character in PowerShell.

Comment: @PetSerAl what the o_O ... well I guess that's gonna be the thing I'm learning today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. I was not parsing through the Get-ChildItem call properly. To correct this a nested `foreach{}` is needed.

```
$file_list = Get-Content "C:\files\Patching\Worker\list.txt"
$bin_folder = "C:\Program Files\NetBrain\Worker Server\bin"
$backups_folder = "C:\files\Patching\Backups"

#Move files from bin to backup
foreach ($item in $file_list) {

 foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $bin_folder) {

   if ($file -like $item) {
      $file_to_move = "C:\Program Files\NetBrain\Worker Server\bin\$file"
      Move-Item $file_to_move $backups_folder
      Add-Content $output_file "$file_to_move"
   }
}
```

}